# What is the purpose of the android .test package?

Tags: android

I noticed that when I launch instrumention tests that a copy of the application is installed on my virtual device with the package extension of `.test`.

For example `com.example` would create a package of `com.example.test` you can see this if you look in the running processes and in the data files.

What is the purpose of the test process/data? I noticed that my activities are running in the `com.example` process, and that any database files I work with aren't created in the associated `.test` directory.

My assumption is that the `.test` process is supposed to be used as a sort of sandbox for your tests so that they don't override any user data. But this isn't happening at all in my use case.

If my assumptions are correct then I would like to know how to configure my project to use the `.test` process/data as intended. How am I supposed to achieve this?

I tried googling and searching on stackoverflow about what the process/data are supposed to be doing but weren't able to find anything. There isn't really anything in the log for the test process either;

```
I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
D/Atlas: Validating map...
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7f9aecc44b60: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
```

The log continues like this with a dozen meaningly calls to `EGL_emulation`, `OpenGLRenderer` and `V/RenderScript`.

Additionally, when I use the Layout Inspector nothing shows up for the appropriate `.test` application.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about `EGL_emulation`, `OpenGLRenderer` and the such. But I'm facing the same problem of `W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar'` with just **some** instrument tests as well and can't find anything. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @Chisko no, i haven't.

Comment: As far as I could see, you get `Asset path '/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar'` when you use `ActivityScenarioRule` with Espresso on old Android APIs. Switching to `ActivityTestRule` launches the test correctly.